# gcc compiler not found

Tags: rhel, rhel5

When I check location of gcc I get correct output. But when I try to get gcc version I get command not found.

I have added the path to $PATH

```
 echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/ptladmin/bin:/usr/libexec/gcc

whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/libexec/gcc

gcc --version
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

I am trying to install a pakcage I keep getting `configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`

```
uname -a
Linux deehxpy011ccpra 2.6.18-419.el5 #1 SMP Wed Feb 22 22:40:57 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The `/usr/libexec/gcc` entry in your `PATH` should probably just be `/usr/libexec`.

Comment: `/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/ptladmin/bin:/usr/libexec/gcc:/usr/libexec` with this path got the same error.

Comment: It sounds like your gcc installation is messed up - try re-installing it.

Comment: Is there anyway to re-install gcc without requiring internet? We cannot use `yum`

Comment: Use your distro ISOs/CDs/DVDs ?